# Help darken stars as they enter the bounds of nebulas

Tags: shader-nodes, layers, panoramic, skybox

I am new to Blender. I am trying to create a skybox of a sort that involves an HDRI and procedurally generated stars, fog, and nebulas. I was following [Kaetsu's Studio tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvkW7PDni40) to create stars and nebulas.

I want the stars to disappear completely or almost completely as they enter the bounds of the nebulas (Blue & Red Nebulas group in the project). I attach [the project file and the HDRI](https://we.tl/t-oXV9hZnjdN) (probably not needed but still) for anyone interested. I saw people doing it by multiplying the RGBs of stars and nebulas (or some other noise), and I tried this option, but it didn't work for me for whatever reason.

I've also tried mixing the nebula and star shaders but they never mixed together correctly: the result was showing either stars only, or nebulas only, or the current result. Furthermore, I tried creating a huge sphere with flipped normals as an alternative to the current layer of nebulas but the star brightness was still passing through. Another attempt I made involved playing around with the Layer Weight node and Less Than node but the result I got, although technically worked, was creating a spherical mask around nebulas that was moving together with the camera movement which is something I don't want.

P.S. This is a duplicate from https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/14cqd6w/help_darken_stars_as_they_enter_the_bounds_of/

Here's a render, but feel free to download the files and play with the scene
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huge shotout to [Samuel Krug](https://www.youtube.com/@samk9632/) for solving my problem.

Basically, I needed to create a mask with ColorRamp based on the texture/rgb brightness (texture Color into colorramp Fac into Fac of the Mix Shader): [image: https://ibb.co/T0mdgWc]

And then you feed that into a mix shader which will mix the stars with a blank shader where the nebulas are:
[image]

The nodes (the important part) look like this:
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please edit your answer to embed the images directly in your post because links can expire and thus invalidate your answer.